# Rails Factory Girl rolling back in the middle of a spec and transactions

Tags: rspec, transactions, factory-bot

I am testing a method on my group model. It relies on creating a few badgetypes through a factory.

Here is the code

```
it "add itself to badges with method add_to_badgetypes" do
    badge = FactoryGirl.create(:badgetype)
    old_badge_ids = badge.group_ids.split(",")
    badge2 = FactoryGirl.create(:badgetype, :group_ids => "3,4,5")
    group.add_to_badgetypes(badge.id, badge2.id)
    expect( badge.group_ids ).to eq( old_badge_ids.push(group.id).join(",") ) 
end
```

'

badge.group_ids' is "200, 300" before, and should be "200,300,#{group.id}" after. When I'm tailing the log, I see this:

```
  `   Badgetype Load (0.5ms)  SELECT group_ids FROM `badge_types` WHERE `badge_types`.`id` = 40 LIMIT 1

   (0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1

   (0.3ms)  UPDATE `badge_types` SET `group_ids` = '200,300,15' WHERE `badge_types`.`id` IS NULL

   (0.2ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1

  Badgetype Load (0.4ms)  SELECT group_ids FROM `badge_types` WHERE `badge_types`.`id` = 41 LIMIT 1

   (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1

   (0.3ms)  UPDATE `badge_types` SET `group_ids` = '3,4,5,15' WHERE `badge_types`.`id` IS NULL

   (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1

   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK

   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
```

`

So it is successfully updating the group_ids, but for some reason the test fails, and if I pp badge.group_ids I get the original value (200,300), and not the updated value.

I assume this has something to do with 'SAVEAPOINT active_record_1', then the UPDATE, and then RELEASE SAVEPOINT. If so, why?

How can I get this spec to pass, as it seems to all be messing up in the db, not the method.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Found out some more interesting information by playing around in the console. If I create a factory and assign it it one line:

```
g = FactoryGirl.create(:group)
```

and then run:

```
g.add_to_badgetype(1,2)
```

I get this SQL

```
1.9.3-p286 :080 > g.add_to_badgetypes(1, 2)
  Badgetype Load (0.5ms)  SELECT group_ids FROM `badge_types` WHERE `badge_types`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  UPDATE `badge_types` SET `group_ids` = 'test,8,9,10' WHERE `badge_types`.`id` IS NULL
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
  Badgetype Load (0.3ms)  SELECT group_ids FROM `badge_types` WHERE `badge_types`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  UPDATE `badge_types` SET `group_ids` = '200,300,8,9,10' WHERE `badge_types`.`id` IS NULL
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
 => [1, 2]
```

Notice the odd UPDATE statement "WHERE badge_types.id IS NULL"

If after I create the factory, I reassign it to a variable and then run the same command, it works find:

```
1.9.3-p286 :081 > g = Group.last
  Group Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `groups`.* FROM `groups` ORDER BY `groups`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Group id: 10, group_name: "Test Group", short_name: "test_group", enrollment: false, kiosk: false, landing: 0, ro_landing: 0> 
1.9.3-p286 :082 > g.add_to_badgetypes(1, 2)
  Badgetype Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `badge_types`.* FROM `badge_types` WHERE `badge_types`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  UPDATE `badge_types` SET `group_ids` = 'test,8,9,10' WHERE `badge_types`.`id` = 1
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
  Badgetype Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `badge_types`.* FROM `badge_types` WHERE `badge_types`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  UPDATE `badge_types` SET `group_ids` = '200,300,8,9,10' WHERE `badge_types`.`id` = 2
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
 => [1, 2]
```

So apparently groups being a factory is causing the SQL update statement to look for ids of NULL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aaaaaaand I figured it out.

I just needed to reload the variable "badgetype"

before the test for equality, I added

@badge.reload

et voila. Weird.

Comment: More information on this problem & why it happens here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815057/why-is-this-rspec-request-spec-not-updating-the-model

Comment: Crazy how much time I spent trying to figure out what was going on and this solved it.